# Include Photos Folder in VB.NET Project

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to use the command below to access the Photos folder in my project:
`Dim filePath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Photos"`

In the folder where my executable is, there are subfolders:
`\bin\Debug`

In which folder should I put my Photos folder, the `Debug` folder or the `root` folder of my project, so that the `Application.StartupPath` command accesses the folder correctly?

Comment: Add a `Photos` folder to the Project. Add the Images you want to include in the build to this folder. For each image file you add, go to its properties and specify `Copy to Output Directory -> Copy if newer`. All images are created in the current build directory (Debug or Release) when you build the application, inside a `Photos` folder. Now `Dim filePath As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Photos")` is always a valid path (also when you publish)

Comment: Do you need the user to be able to write to the folder (e.g., to add photos), or is it only for reading files from?

Comment: @Jimi one piece of information, the Project will not record anything in the folder, it will only be used for an image to be shown in a picturebox1... I didn't understand your answer regarding `go to its properties and specify Copy to Output Directory`?. .. should I create the Photo folder in the root directory of the project or not?

Comment: @Andrew Morton the Photos folder will be read-only, the project will not write anything to the folder, it will only fetch the images to show in picturebox1.

Comment: If that folder is not used as read-only storage (data you only read from), you probably better create that folder in `Application.CommonAppDataPath`: you always have write access to this directory. Instead, when you deploy and the application is installed in `Program Files`, you may not have write access -- That being said, if you just need a temporary file as storage for transient data, you can simply use `Path.GetTempFileName`, to get an unique random file name that points to the User's `Temp` folder. You delete that file after use

Comment: @Jimi I think I'm not understanding your concept!... my I have a Photos folder that has all the images I need inside it, my project already has an executable, in the folder where the executable is, logically, there is already the bin folder and the Debug folder. My intention is to place this Photos folder inside my existing project directory. That's why I asked if it has to be in the root directory, where the executable is or inside Debug. I want to run the simple command so that when I click on the Photo button on my form, it already opens in the folder where the photos are, that's it!

Comment: Well, you said *the Project will not record anything in the folder*, but you apparently are storing data in this folder -- This scenario is what I described in my first comment: move the `Photos` folder you have in `bin\Debug\Photos` somewhere else, possibly outside the Project directory structure. Add a `Photo` folder to the Project in Solution Explorer. Right-click on it and use `Add -> Existing Item...`. Select your images. After the images are added to the folder, select them all and, from the Properties pane, select `Copy to Output Directory -> Copy if newer`

Comment: The `Photos` directory is created in both `bin\Debug\Photos` and `bin\Release\Photos` when you build with the Release Profile. Also, the images are added to a setup Project when you publish the application

Comment: @Jimi you said `move the Photos folder you have in bin\Debug\Photos`... but I still don't have any Photos folder in my project, the Photos folder is on my desktop, ie the project has no Photos. .. this is when I'm going to implement this in him, understand?

Comment: Well, since the folder is already somewhere else, then skip the first step

Comment: @Jimi Ok, I'll do that... another question: After the folder is included in the project, can I manually add a new image to the Photos folder?... if so, which folder do I add the new image to, in the Photos folder in `root directory`, photos folder in `bin\Debug\Photos`, or photos folder in `bin\Release\Photos`?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. Add new images to the `Photos` folder you have created in the Project, in Solution Explorer. Remember to select the file after you have added it, go to its Properties and again select `Copy to Output Directory -> Copy if newer`

Comment: @Jimi so I can't just open the explorer in Windows and include an image in the Project's Photos folder?... I'll always have to do this process via Visual Studio, is that it?

Comment: You can do that, too. Select the file to set its properties after the file appears in Solution Explorer

Comment: @Jimi actually the question is related to another subject, I already deleted it, thanks!

Comment: @Jimi following your instructions, it worked. Could you post an answer so I can select it? Thanks.